# Open 3rd party application(It is also my application) from a application in KIOSK mode android L(5.1 api level 22)

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have successfully implemented KIOSK mode application and I am able to block the user to particular application.My requirement is,I have to enable KIOSK mode in my tablet using my application and then I need to allow user to open 3rd party(my another) application which is pre installed in my tablet through my KIOSK app.I am able to open the application from a samsung s6 edge with Android N(api 25) and Marshmallow device(api 23).But when I tested with samsung 5.1 tablet,I am unable to open my application through Kisok app.It is showing me "Screen is pinned.Unpinning isn't allowed by your organisation."Any help is appreciated.

I have added my two applications(Kisok and my application) package names when setting lock mode.Same piece of code is working on 6.0,6.1,7.0,7.1 but not in 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100248/allow-particular-app-other-than-device-owner-app-android). Kiosk features have been significantly improved in Android Marshmallow which might explain why you cannot achieve the same behavior on Android Lollipop.

The [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=45993769) provided by Google should offer backward compatibility on Android Lollipop, and in particular allow to run an app in kiosk mode with the following policy copied from [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy#for_devices_running_multiple_apps_from_a_custom_launcher) of documentation.

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.example.custom_launcher",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "lockTaskAllowed": true,
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  },
  {
    "packageName": "com.example.app1",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "lockTaskAllowed": true,
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  }
],
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
  {
    "receiverActivity": "com.example.custom_launcher",
    "actions": [
      "android.intent.action.MAIN"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "android.intent.category.HOME",
      "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have set {mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName, new String[]{getPackageName(), "{AppPackagNameToOpen}"} );}.But of no use.I was wandering to open another app from my app which has locktask package permission.But not in success for pre marshmallow.